# Select column by number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

I have a small issue with Excel. I doing transformations for some columns in the dataset. I know the number of the columns I want, but I wasn't able to use them in a formula. For example I want to add the 5th and the 10th column. How do I write this formula?

Note: I have tried the R1C1 reference style but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You may have to write a custom function that works out column 1 = A, column 2 = B, column 27 = AA, column 28 = AB etc. Your function should take a number and return a letter(s)

Comment: wow that's sad! I am not an excel user! I think I will do this in some other software then! thank you very much :)

Comment: Excel functions aren't too difficult to learn!

Comment: True, I am planning to learn them, but it is a matter of time for me now. Much appreciated :)

Comment: What Excel version? I have an answer for 2010 (just tested and works a treat)

Comment: What do you mean "add the column"?

Comment: @BigChris, Yes I am using Excel 2010 as well.

Comment: @Raystafarian simple addition, like add all the values in column 5 to all the values in column 10 and give me the result in a new column

Comment: What requirement is driving you to refer to columns by number instead of label?  i.e. what are you really trying to accomplish?  Why can't you use SUM(E:E,J:J)?

Comment: I have a program in R that gives me the column numbers that I should be adding or deleting. It is a long story. The case is I have reference as numbers and I wanted to analyse that in Excel. Anyway I am doing it the long way for now. I will try to learn that later. Cheers.

Comment: Grr, I think I spoke too soon. What I have returns a column letter as a string, but the moment I go to use it in a formula I get `#NAME` error... I think it's because I'm using a string rather than a reference... damn Excel!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A:$A,0,5-1),OFFSET($A$:$A,0,10-1))
```

Substitute 5 & 10 with calculations or cell references containing column numbers if needed.